# How to run pman on a remote node in erlang?

Tags: erlang

I need debug my ejabberd server and I want use pman for this purpose. But I have only access via ssh and server worked in screen.

I do:

```
ssh mydoman@example.com

erl -sname test@localhost
(test@localhost)1> pman:start().
<0.123.0>

and it works but I need get access to 'ejabberd@localhost' node from same machine

now I press Ctrl+G
--> r'ejabberd@localhos'
--> c

(ejabberd@localhost)1> pman:start().
** exited: {startup_timeout,pman} **
```

And my question is - how do I run pman properly?

Answer (score 4):

Pman needs access to the screen on which it runs. I understand that you are running distributed erlang on both nodes and that they are connected and know of each other. The easiest way is then to run `pman` locally on your node, `pman:start()`. There is a `Nodes` menu which should contain all known nodes and if you pick `ejabbered@localhost` you should see all the processes on that node.

Comment: Obviously this is a more direct answer, have an upvote sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about pman, but if you want to monitor a remote node I've create entop for that purpose. It might not work exactly like pman but should be close enough.

https://github.com/mazenharake/entop